# How to get recent values in this db?

Tags: django

I use sqlite.

```
class Member(models.Model):
    member_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    is_update = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    member_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    member_group = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    room_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    bed_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    gender = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    birth_date = models.DateField()
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=11)
    protector = models.CharField(default='protector',max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.member_id)

    def initIsUpdate(self):
        self.is_update = 0
        return 0
```

```
class Inpatient(models.Model):
    member_id = models.ForeignKey(Member, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column = 'member_id', related_name='member')
    inpatient_status = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    is_in_room = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    is_on_bed = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    heart_rate = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    breath_rate = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    update_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
    protector_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.member_id)
```

And Members are 4 people..

Each Members have same values in Inpatient DB.

It gets new queryset for every 1 sec.

And I want get 4 Member's most recent Inpatient DB.

How I get that DB??

Comment: What do you mean by "most recent"? Do you want to get the record with the latest `update_time`? Or use the `id` field to infer the creation order?

Answer (score 0):

```
class Inpatient(models.Model):
    member_id = models.ForeignKey(Member, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column = 'member_id', related_name='member')
    inpatient_status = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    is_in_room = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    is_on_bed = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    heart_rate = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    breath_rate = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    update_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
    protector_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    class Meta:
        get_latest_by = "update_time"
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.member_id)
```

Now when you filter the members in views.py it will provide recent values..